# libpng - RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG when using images created by Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, libpng

I am trying to train a YOLOv8 detection model. Since I couldn't find a dataset that fits my project's purpose, I've decided to create my own dataset by overlaying images on top of a background image. To achieve this, I used Python's PIL package. However, a few errors consistently show up when training the YOLO model.

Below is the code I used to generate images.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageCms
from glob import glob
from tqdm import tqdm

import numpy as np
import os
import shutil
import random
import sys

def overlay_and_resize_pillow(background_image_path, overlay_image_path, output_image_path, white):
    # Open the background and overlay images
    if white:
        background = Image.new(mode="RGBA", size=(random.randint(512, 1024), random.randint(512, 1024)), color="white")
    else:
        background = Image.open(background_image_path).resize((random.randint(512, 1024), random.randint(512, 1024)))
    overlay = Image.open(overlay_image_path)
    
    profile = ImageCms.createProfile("sRGB")

    # Generate a random scale factor for resizing the overlay image
    scale_factor = random.uniform(0.5, 1.2)

    # Resize the overlay image based on the scale factor
    overlay_resized = overlay.resize((int(overlay.width * scale_factor), int(overlay.height * scale_factor)))

    # Get the dimensions of the resized overlay image
    overlay_width, overlay_height = overlay_resized.size

    # Calculate the valid range for overlay position to ensure it fits within the background
    max_x_offset = background.width - overlay_width
    max_y_offset = background.height - overlay_height

    # Calculate the position to overlay the resized image on the background
    x_offset = random.randint(0, max_x_offset)
    y_offset = random.randint(0, max_y_offset)

    # Create a copy of the background to overlay the resized image
    background_copy = background.copy()

    # Paste the resized overlay image onto the background copy
    background_copy.paste(overlay_resized, (x_offset, y_offset), overlay_resized)

    # Save the output image
    background_copy.save(output_image_path, icc_profile=ImageCms.ImageCmsProfile(profile).tobytes())
#     background_copy.save(output_image_path)
    
    name = output_image_path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    
    cl = '0'
    width = overlay_width / background.width
    height = overlay_height / background.height
    
    x_center = (x_offset + overlay_width / 2) / background.width
    y_center = (y_offset + overlay_height / 2) / background.height
    
    with open(f'./chartdetection/labels/train/{name}.txt', 'w+') as f:
        f.write(' '.join(map(str, [cl, x_center, y_center, width, height])))
```

When training, I keep getting these errors

- libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'ICC Profile': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG
- libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

How should I modify my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your image to RGB before trying to save it with a color profile:

```
    background_copy = background_copy.convert("RGB")
    # Save the output image
    ...
```